# The drag and drop function doesn't work in Angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I am using Angular 7 and following this tutorial.
[Tutorial](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)

I copy and paste the sample source code but it's not working.
The box is displayed but I cannot move it.

Here is the source code.

HTML

```
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag>
   Drag me around
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .example-box {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     border: solid 1px #ccc;
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
     cursor: move;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     text-align: center;
     background: #fff;
     border-radius: 4px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     transition: box-shadow 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
     box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
                 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.example-box:active {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
              0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

Component file(.ts)

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Drag&Drop with a handle
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'map-manifest',
  templateUrl: './map.manifest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.manifest.component.css'],
})
export class MapManifestComponent {}
```

Anybody know what's the problem?
Please help me if you know this.

Comment: Create the stackblitz demo to get the fix quicker.

Comment: Did you import the DragDropModule into the NgModule?

Comment: Start by importing `DragDropModule` into the `NgModule` where you want to use drag-and-drop features. You can now add the `cdkDrag` directive to elements to make them draggable.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I've imported the DragDropModule and copied the examples verbatim. I've even used this in other projects but for some reason it isn't working in this project. Did you have any luck with this?